# Moq Does Not Preserve Property Values

Tags: c#, moq

I have a mocked object in my unit tests that has a property.  At a certain point in my test, the code blows up because that property returns null, even though it was just set to a non-null value.  I have tried using `SetupAllProperties()`, `SetupProperty()` with just that property, and explicitly building `SetupGet` and `SetupSet`

```
setAlignment = new Alignment();
mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.SetupAllProperties();

mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.SetupSet(r => r.SetAlignment = It.IsAny<Alignment>()).Callback<Alignment>(value => setAlignment = value);
mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.SetupGet(r => r.SetAlignment).Returns(() => setAlignment);

mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.Setup(r => r.Randomize()).Returns(mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.Object.SetAlignment);
mockSetLevelRandomizer.Setup(r => r.Randomize()).Returns(mockSetLevelRandomizer.Object.SetLevel);

mockAlignmentGenerator.Setup(f => f.GenerateWith(mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.Object)).Returns(() => mockSetAlignmentRandomizer.Object.SetAlignment);
mockAlignmentGenerator.Setup(f => f.GenerateWith(mockAnyAlignmentRandomizer.Object)).Returns(() => new Alignment());
```

The problem occurs with the `AlignmentGenerator` when it gets here:

```
do setAlignmentRandomizer.SetAlignment = alignmentGenerator.GenerateWith(anyAlignmentRandomizer);
while (allowedAlignments.Contains(setAlignmentRandomizer.SetAlignment.ToString()) == false);
```

Even though I can confirm that the generator spits out a new `Alignment` object, the property on `setAlignmentRandomizer` is always `null`, which makes the whole evaluation throw an unexpected error.  Yes, I have also confirmed that the `allowedAlignments` collection (created elsewhere in the code) is also not null. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is that I am a dork.  The setup for this whole test class is very convoluted, unfortunately, and in the midst of the chaos, I missed that I was accidentally newing up that mock more than once - I properly set up the properties the first time, but then newed it up the second time, and lost all that setup.