# Moq - Return Different Type From Parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a mock (using Moq) that takes in an `IEnumerable<T>` and return an item from that collection (`T`).  When trying to set up a mock, I run into this issue:

```
mockCollectionsSelector.SetupSequence(s => s.SelectRandomFrom<Feat>(It.Is<IEnumerable<Feat>>(fs => fs.All(f => f.Name == FeatConstants.FavoredEnemy))))
            .Returns((IEnumerable<Feat> fs) => fs.ElementAt(1))
```

`Cannot convert lambda expression because it is not a delegate type`

All the examples of referencing parameters in Moq have the same return type as what was passed in, so this might not even be possible - and if so, then I will have to find a different way to do this.  Otherwise, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I concur with @gisek this should work. Could you show the implementation of the method SelectRandomFrom?

Comment: Considering that this is a mock, the implementation details don't matter

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code by replacing Feat class with int:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void ShouldDoSomething()
        {
            Mock<ICollectionSelector> mockCollectionsSelector = new Mock<ICollectionSelector>();
            mockCollectionsSelector
                .Setup(s => s.SelectRandomFrom(It.Is<IEnumerable<int>>(fs => fs.All(f => true))))
                .Returns((IEnumerable<int> fs) => fs.ElementAt(1));  
                //.Returns<IEnumerable<int>>(fs => fs.ElementAt(1)); // this also works and is more readable I guess
            var selector = mockCollectionsSelector.Object;
            var number = selector.SelectRandomFrom(new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7});
            Assert.IsTrue(number == 2);
        }
    }

    public interface ICollectionSelector
    {
        int SelectRandomFrom<T>(IEnumerable<T> @is);
    }
}
```

It works fine. The 'test' passes. Maybe try upgrading your Moq library to the latest version? I used 4.2.1507.118 on .Net 4.5.2

Comment: That is the version of Moq I am using.  The library is .Net 4.5.1.  However, when I originally posted, I did another simplification that might have caused another problem.  I am not using `Setup`, but `SetupSequence` - and the `Return` for `SetupSequence` apparently doesn't have a generic override :/  I also wonder if the issue is that the type I am using (`Feat`) is not a primitive,and maybe the lambda can't handle that?

Comment: @cidthecoatrack I guess it has nothing to do with the Feat class. If you give me a copy-paste failing example i can give it a further look.

Comment: Here is an exact copy of code that currently fails: `mockCollectionsSelector.SetupSequence(s => s.SelectRandomFrom<Feat>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Feat>>())).Returns((IEnumerable<Feat> fs) => fs.ElementAt(1))`

Comment: @cidthecoatrack In your question you asked about Setup method. In your comment however you ask about SetupSequence mentod. SetupSequence method (unlike Setup) doesn't have an overload that takes Func. It can only take a solid value.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  Then I was right, that I will have to find another way to accomplish this.  Thank you.  I will edit the question to have the sequence code.  If you can post that the functionality does not exist with that as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Also, if you would be so kind, @gisek , could you look at another Moq question I have?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431698/moq-does-not-preserve-property-values